# Change right-click context menu options in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, customization

When I right-click in my class library, I get some quick options to create things, like an Item from the popup list (**New Item...**), a User Control, etc. E.g.

[alt text http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/6527/clipboard02vw.jpg](http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/6527/clipboard02vw.jpg)

Now in my web app project, I'd like to be able to get the User Control listed in the right-click menu just like Component and Class, so I don't have to click **New Item...** then choose it from there.

[alt text http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/2563/clipboard01jo.jpg](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/2563/clipboard01jo.jpg)

Is there a way to do this in the configuration? I can't seem to figure it out in VS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools -> Customize -> Check "Context Menus" -> Project and Solution Context Menus

It should be one of those menus